# How to update Cyangenmod 10.1 to 10.2?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean, 4.3-jelly-bean, sony-xperia-z

I have Cyangenmod 10.1.3 installed on my Xperia Z. When I tried to download Cyangenmod 10.2-20131101 nightly build in my phone's settings, no error but it silently failed after some time. I tried again but the problem persists.

Any idea what went wrong?

Am I supposed to download the zip file, copy it to my phone and boot into recovery mode to do a manual installation?

Comment: I'm not a CM user so I don't know for sure, but I don't believe nightly builds support OTA updating. If you're desperate to test a nightly, you have to flash it manually.

Comment: @Dan is correct - you need to flash it manually through CWM or TWRP. I also think that you need to perform a factory reset when upgrading from 10.1 to 10.2 but I can't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't upgrade form 10.1.3 to 10.2 directly. You must flash it manually from recovery and you also have to wipe data.

Answer (score 2):

You should follow these steps:

1. Download the relevant ZIP file from get.cm
2. Copy the downloaded ZIP file to your devices storage card
3. Using an app such as [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup), do a complete backup of all your installed applications.
4. Boot into recovery, and follow these steps:

   1. Wipe data (all data)
   2. Install the zip file as usual
5. Once done, reboot device.
6. Using the backup app, restore your apps.
7. Reboot device.

You will now be running the latest version. The data wipe is highly recommended, but your device should still work without it - you *must* wipe the dalvik cache at the *very* least however, or you'll get a boot loop.

**Important Note**

If you use google apps (GApps) then you *must* make sure you download the version for CM 10.2. If you do not, you may experience compatibility errors.

Comment: CM 10 and above includes self-updater.  Go to `Settings -> About device` and you should see an option for updating CM.  You can choose which updates to download (stable vs. RC vs. nightly,) and download them from there.  Once the download completes, you'll have the option to boot to Recovery and apply it automatically.  Or you can still do it manually from `/sdcard/cmupdate/` folder.

Comment: @Chahk when using that method, you must remember to reinstall the GApps. Also, I don't trust the CM Updater as much as I should.

Answer (score 0):

[Several](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/74526-how-do-i-update-cyanogenmod/#entry402538) [sources](http://hub.cm/blog/upgrading-cm-101-cm-102) state that no wipe is needed while updating CM 10.1 to 10.2:

> You can also do this manually (which is required if you flash
>   additional things like kernels), by downloading the update to your
>   sdcard (from http://get.cm) and rebooting into recovery to flash the
>   update (and any additional zips - although, if you have the gapps
>   installed from http://goo.im/gapps, there is no need to reflash
>   those).
>
> Contrary to popular belief, there is no need to wipe ANYTHING when you
>   update CM. This includes your cache partition, your dalvik cache, and
>   your battery stats. While wiping these won’t hurt anything, you can
>   increase the time it takes to boot up CM after you install the update.
>   Android is smart enough to manage both your cache and dalvik cache
>   without you intervening.

I faced no issues after following this advice.